# Why would html source not change when the DOM is updated dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, browser

I had posted one question earlier [jQuery inconsistency in setting readonly attribute in IE-8 and FF-3.5.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381621/jquery-inconsistency-in-setting-readonly-attribute-in-ie-8-and-ff-3-5-8) and was quite happy with the answer.

But I did notice that if you update (any??) DOM elements dynamically, then view source (using browser's view source) I find the updated DOM element attribute retains its older value(before update). However, if you use Firebug/IE Developer toolbar, it displays the updated DOM

Example:http://gutfullofbeer.net/readonly.html

FF3.5-View page Source:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $('input.readonly').attr('readonly', true);//set input with CSS class readonly to readonly
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type='text' class='readonly' maxlength='20' value='Blort'>This one is read-only<br>
    <input type='text' maxlength='20' value='Fish'>This one is not read-only<br>

  </body>
</html>
```

Here the first text box is set to readonly in jQuery's `document.ready` method. Viewing the source with browser would give a markup like

```
<input type='text' class='readonly' maxlength='20' value='Blort'>
```

and Firebug will give something like

```
<input type="text" value="Blort" maxlength="20" class="readonly" readonly="">
```

IE8 Developer toolbar:

`<input class="readonly" type="text" maxLength="20" readOnly="readonly" value="Blort"/>`

So my guess is that the browser (IE8/FF3.5) generates the html source much earlier before DOM events kick in (in my case it is jQuery's `document.ready()` )

Can someone tell me whats happening behind the scene ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The view source is the source downloaded to the browser.  What happens in memory doesn't get updated in the source.

Comment: as the source is server side and Dom is manipulated on the client side.

Comment: Technically, the source doesn't "have" to be server side.  You could load it by accessing a page locally on the drive.

Answer (score 3):

Several browsers have DOM inspectors, for example, Safari 4.0 has a great DOM browser that helps you view dynamically generated elements and their CSS styles dynamically.

Comment: assume it is similar to Firebug/IE Developer toolbar ?

Comment: @Ram yes, it is the same idea.